# header dropdown menues overlapping in mobile resolution

Tags: html, css

As shown in this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIEdt.png) (mobile resolution), header dropdown submenus are overlapping. Any solutions to display them properly?

```html
<li class="dropdown">
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" id="nav-opt7">Media<span class="caret"></span></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu wow fadeIn">
    <li><a href="image-gallery.php">Images</a></li>
    <li><a href="video-gallery.php">Videos</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: try clear: both; in contact div or href

Comment: below is my code,Please check

Comment: <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" id="nav-opt7">Media<span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu wow fadeIn">
       <li><a href="image-gallery.php">Images</a></li>
       <li><a href="video-gallery.php">Videos</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>

Comment: please try i am not sure but just try
 li {
    clear: both;
}

Comment: i tried sir, its not working properly

Answer (score 1):

Try to set padding top style for `li` and only for mobile version using media query, like below,

```
@media screen and (max-width: 650px) and (min-width: 0px) 
{
  Your li element style or padding top style for your li element
}
```